# Tool for checking/proving the appearance of a product in the market

Tags: search, product, tools

I was wondering if there is a tool / a database or something different that can be used to show the **date of appearance** of certain products in the market.

It could perhaps be something similar to the "wayback machine" at https://archive.org/ , even if it cannot be used in courts.

If I recall correctly, patent examiners have to rely on the information shown in printed journals. But is there an electronic equivalent for quick searches?

Answer (score 1):

The Wayback Machine is actually the closest thing available for this too, even if it's not quite the main purpose. This should show, in most cases, at least when a product is offered for sale. Though its dating is relatively coarse, and it certainly wouldn't do anything to show non-Internet offers, nor actual sales.

Archive.org is actually prior art too, since it contains documents which are available to the public at a given date.  I have seen examiners (particularly in Europe) rely on it as such.